# pupeteer : is it possible to pause/resumethe script to modify the script?

Tags: puppeteer

1) I wonder if it is possible to pause the execution of the script to get access to the developer console in order to modify the script in runtime.

2) or maybe to run pupeteer on an opened chrome tab ?